# Writing custom middleware in Django 2.2, control not coming to __call__() method at all

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create custom middleware within Django 2.2 application

Below is my settings file :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
     'html_template.middleware.CorsMiddleware'
]
```

and my middleware code is:

```
class CorsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
       import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
       self.get_response = get_response
       # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
      import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
      # Code to be executed for each request before
      # the view (and later middleware) are called.

      response = self.get_response(request)

      # Code to be executed for each request/response after
      # the view is called.

      return response
```

Now according to Django 2.2  documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/

`__call__()` method should be executed every time a request hits the server, but the weird part is even though the `__init__()` method is executed but the control never reaches the `__call__()` method. Any thoughts?

Comment: What URL are you going to in your browser? What status code is the response? Is that the real `MIDDLEWARE` list or are there other middlewares there?

Comment: Hey @Alasdair, the URL is - localhost:8000/templates/. It's the only list and the __init__() is getting called for this middleware.

Comment: I hit the breakpoint in `__call__` when I try your middleware in a new project. There must be something about your code that you  haven't included. Using that `MIDDLEWARE` setting is hard - you get errors unless you remove some `django.contrib` apps from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: What's the version of Django are you using? can you share  INSTALLED_APPS you used?

Comment: I tested 2.2.15 because you said you were using 2.2. I used `INSTALLED_APPS = []`, because when I used the default `INSTALLED_APPS` for a new project with `MIDDLEWARE = ['html_template.middleware.CorsMiddleware']`, I got errors like `?: (admin.E408) 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.`.

Comment: Can you share your settings file? I have the same version of Django and it's still not working out for me.

Comment: I started a fresh project, and `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE` are the only settings I changed.

Comment: It's weird, I execution flow reached the ```__call__()``` when I called it using 127.0.0.1:8000/templates/. But was not working for localhost:8000. not sure why.

Comment: Perhaps your browser has cached the response for `localhost:8000` so the request isn't hitting Django. The middleware works for me, so unless you can provide an example that doesn't work in a new project, I can't help you debug it any further.